# Direct sum of two points on an elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography

Given $E:y^{2} = x^{3}+9x$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{71}$, and $A = (0,0), \: B = (1,9)$, I'm asked to find $C=A\oplus B$. I just don't know how the direct sum of two points on an elliptic curve is defined, or if this symbol has a different meaning in the context of EC. Can somebody help me?

Comment: This is explained in detail at the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve), see section "Group Law". There are also given very helpful pictures for it, e.g., for the associativity of this new addition. Furthermore compare with your question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1463741/adding-points-on-an-elliptic-curve?rq=1).

Comment: I recommend Silverman and Tate's book [Rational Points on Elliptic Curves](https://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/RPECHome.html), which gives a nice foundation for such calculations and important additional topics (such as the relationship to primality testing and factorization).

Comment: If you haven't already done so, I recommend looking through [previous Questions on this topic](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=addition+elliptic+curve+is%3Aquestion) at Math.SE.   Note that the "addition" of two points with integer coordinates will often produce fractional coordinates in $\mathbb{Q}$, which is obviated by working over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{71}$.